# Adding functionality to Vuetify component, mass pass in props

Tags: vue.js

I want to be able to send props to a Vuetify component without needing to assign each one within my component, is there a way I can just mass pass in all of the props?

Below is what i'm currently doing, however there's a lot of prop'.

I have attempted to simply extend the VSelect component, however this returns multiple errors which don't seem simple to fix!

```
<template>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6>
        <v-select v-model="selected" :items="data"
                  :label="label"
                  :multiple="multiple"
                  :chips="chips"
                  :hint="hint"
                  :persistent-hint="persistentHint"
                  :counter="counter"
                  :dark="dark"
        ></v-select>
    </v-flex>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            label: {
                default: false,
                type: String|Boolean
            },
            multiple: {
                default: true,
                type: Boolean
            },
            chips: {
                default: true,
                type: Boolean
            },
            hint: {
                default: '',
                type: String|Boolean
            },
            persistentHint: {
                default: this.hint !== '' || this.hint !== false,
                type: String|Boolean
            },
            counter: {
                default: false,
                type: Number|Boolean
            },
            dark: {
                default: false,
                type: Boolean
            },
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                selected: [ ],
                data: [
                    'test', 'test2', 'test3'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass props as an object:

```
<v-select
  v-model="selected" 
  :items="data"
  v-bind="$props"
></v-select>
```

[ https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object ]